# Can anyone explain my error in tensorflow?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am getting an input shape error in tensorflow while trying to train my model. I have checked the input shapes match up, but I am still getting an error, any help would be appreciated. The shape of X is (1, 7) and the shape of y is (1, 2).
I have this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
import numpy as np
import json

with open("situations.json") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

X = np.array([i[0] for i in data])
y = np.array([i[1] for i in data])
print(X)
print(y)

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(7,)),
    keras.layers.Dense(7),
    keras.layers.Dense(2)
])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)
```

The file "situations.json" has this in it and I have tried using more data (but it got deleted):

```
[
  [[60, 60, -1, -1, -1, -5, 0], [0, 0]]
]
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CarSim.py", line 20, in <module>
    model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)
  File "\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training.py", line 1239, in fit
    validation_freq=validation_freq)
  File "\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\training_arrays.py", line 196, in fit_loop
    outs = fit_function(ins_batch)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\backend.py", line 3740, in __call__
    outputs = self._graph_fn(*converted_inputs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1081, in __call__
    return self._call_impl(args, kwargs)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1121, in _call_impl
    return self._call_flat(args, self.captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 1224, in _call_flat
    ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\function.py", line 511, in call
    ctx=ctx)
  File "\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\eager\execute.py", line 67, in quick_execute
    six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_from
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InternalError:  Blas GEMM launch failed : a.shape=(1, 7), b.shape=(7, 7), m=1, n=7, k=7
     [[node dense_1/MatMul (defined at \lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\framework\ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_691]

Function call stack:
keras_scratch_graph
```

I have tried using more data in the situations.json file, tried different loss functions and neural network architecture, but always come across some sort of error, this being one of them. I know it is to do with input shape, but I can't fix it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the output, you omitted the part where you print your X and y. In any case, it seems  to me that your shapes are wrong. You should check that the X and y that you throw into the fit method have the correct shape. Here is a modified version of your code without json that works and should help getting the shapes right.

```
# tested with tf 1.14 and python 3.6
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np


X = np.array([[60, 60, -1, -1, -1, -5, 0], [60, 60, -1, -1, -1, -5, 0], [60, 60, -1, -1, -1, -5, 0]])
y = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [11, 2]])

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(7,)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(7),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2)
])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="mean_squared_error")
model.fit(X, y, epochs=100)
```

As a sidenote, if you're training on json data, you might want to look into tfrecords.

Comment: I tried your code in tensorflow-gpu 2 in python 3.7. But I still got a very similar error. Also, the X shape is (1, 7) and the y shape is (1, 2)

Comment: I tested my code with tf-cpu 2 (Python 3.6) and it works there as well. I don't have tf-gpu 2 installed on my home laptop so I can't test it there. I would be very surprised, however, if this depended on the tensorflow version... Note that I am using tf.keras as opposed to keras that you are using.

Comment: Note that keras and tf.keras are separate libraries.

Comment: I just re-ran and I got the error again, on tf.keras.

Comment: I have now got it working on tensorflow cpu, but it still errors on gpu.

Comment: The gpu version of tensorflow 2 can be a bit tricky to install correctly (which is why I don't have it right now). It is pretty strange to me, however, that the error that comes up is concerned with data shapes. Have you ever managed to train any neural network on your tf-gpu 2 version?

Comment: Yes. I have done most of the tensorflow tutorials on gpu, but this is the first time I'm doing something by myself.

Comment: This sounds very strange. If you have done the tutorials, surely you have already successfully trained a simple network such as this. You can then go back to the tutorial code and modify it to your needs. This should enable you to find the point at which the error occurs. 

By the way, to make sure you run the same code as the answers you get, assuming the code is complete as in this case, I think it best to really copy-paste it, just to make sure no detail was missed.

Comment: Thank you for the help, I have now got it working fully and the network is working as expected! The trained network works on gpu, but it still can't be trained on gpu.